# Some incoming email formats do not work in my SMTP server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, incoming-email, smtp, email-enabled-library

I have a single server farm (a hyper-v virtual machine) and I want to send emails to one of my document libraries. I have followed [this msdn article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262947(v=office.15).aspx) to configure the SMTP server in my VM.

When I insert an `.msg` file to `C:\inetpub\mailroot\Pickup` it handles it as bad email but when I save my emails as `.eml` files it sends them to the document library.

Why does it not send `.msg` files to the document library?

Comment: what error you are getting? couple of things to check, if .msg included into block file type, also change the type.."by changing the encoding type from MIME to UUEncode or BinHex."

Comment: No errors it just adds three files in bademails folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSG files are a proprietary format only recognized by Microsoft Outlook. The only format the Windows SMTP service understands are EML files.

**UPDATE**

You just can't save an Outlook MSG file directly into SharePoint or Windows SMTP Server. You need either an Exchange Server or any other SMTP/POP/IMAP server Outlook can communicate with.

I personally use the free and open source [hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com/) on my DEV machine to test incoming and outgoing SharePoint e-mail capabilities.

Comment: Does it means that I can not send email to my list from outlook?

Comment: See my updated answer.